# How to calculate asymptotic of Supertransparent potential of the Dirac equation?

Tags: calculus, asymptotics

> > The Supertransparent potential  of  the  Dirac equation
> >
> > $v(x)= \frac{4\lambda_{1}(\sin2\theta-2\lambda_{1}\gamma \cos2\theta)}{\sin^{2}2\theta-4\lambda_{1}^{2}\gamma^{2}},\quad (1)$
> >
> > where
> >
> > $\theta=\lambda_{1}(x+x_{1}(\lambda_{1})),\; \gamma = x+x_{2},\; x_{2} = x_{1}+\lambda_{1}\partial_{\lambda_{1}}x_{1}(\lambda_{1})$.
> >
> > This potential has obviously two first-order poles determined by
> >
> > $\sin^{2}2\theta-4\lambda_{1}^{2}\gamma^{2}=0,$
> >
> > whose exact location can be fine-tuned by the choice  of  the  parameters  $\lambda_{1},\;x_{1}$  and  $x_{2}$ . For
> >     $x  \rightarrow \pm \infty$,  one obtains the asymptotic estimate
> >
> > $v(x) = \frac{2}{\lambda_{1}x}\cos2\theta\left[1+O(\frac{1}{x})\right] \quad (2)$
> >
> > How to get (2) from (1)?

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Comment: @user619894, When we use $\sin^{2}2\theta-4\lambda_{1}^{2}\gamma^{2}=0$ in (1), we have undefined solution. I don't know how to go ahead?

Comment: The positions of the poles are not necessarily  related to the asymptotics of large $|x|$